# why when retrieving data from my firestore database do i get &*nbsp; instead of space and how do i fix this?

Tags: css, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am using a reactjs app that runs firebase firestor.

why when retrieving data from my firestore database do i get   instead of space and how do I fix this?

This is the output I retrieved from firestore.

[image]

to give help to expolain how to replicate this.

first i put it int he database.

It appeared just as it does in the picture.

Then i took it out of the database.

this was don through an input field where I typed in the words given./
THen it was taken out through the get().then(doc => doc.data() process needed to remove anything from the firestore datadbase.

as the only problem is in the removal part

to remove:

```
const [data, setData] =useState({BIo:""});

    firebase.Firestore().collection("contractors").doc(id).get().then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
            console.log("Document data:", doc.data());  
              setData(doc.data());


return(<div>  {data.bio} </div>)
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: done, though i am really struggling to see how i needed to do that since it is so self explanatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure whats cause that, it is weird. you might want to take a look at how you're handling inputs.

this could a temp fix.

```
var textWithNBSpaceReplaced = originalText. replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ')
```

Comment: So is this not a normal occurrence in firestore?

Comment: it's not normal, as Levinson said it's probably how you are handling the input. Check the Firestore admin panel and see if the values are there. if they are it's most likely how you handle input or something between input -> upload

Comment: Yeah, it was a saetup thing witht he firebase-react-reduc-boilerplate...